# Trying to Install Grunt-Shopify

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, shopify

(https://github.com/wilr/grunt-shopify)

I am very new to anything related to grunt and node.js

Here is the error I am getting:

- 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
- 1 verbose cli [ 'node',
- 1 verbose cli   'C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
- 1 verbose cli   'install',
- 1 verbose cli   'grunt-shopify',
- 1 verbose cli   '--save-dev' ]
- 2 info using npm@2.4.1
- 3 info using node@v0.10.36
- 4 verbose stack Error: EISDIR, read
- 5 verbose cwd C:\Users\Steven\Desktop\Sublime Text 2\shop
- 6 error Windows_NT 6.2.9200
- 7 error argv "node" "C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "grunt-shopify" "--save-dev"
- 8 error node v0.10.36
- 9 error npm  v2.4.1
- 10 error code EISDIR
- 11 error errno 28
- 12 error EISDIR, read
- 13 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
- 13 error     http://github.com/npm/npm/issues
- 14 verbose exit [ 28, true ]

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?? We think it may be a permission issue even though we are running command prompt as admin.

Thanks!

Comment: This error message is not very help but can you tell me what command you are executing to do the install ? I think your package.json file is missing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The code I am executing is: npm install grunt-shopify --save-dev

Comment: `--save-dev` is going to dump the the install package specs, in this case grunt-shopify into the `package.json` file. Make sure that file exists and that you are executing this command at the root of your project where the `package.json` file is.

Comment: Okay. my root file consists of 'shop', 'Gruntfile.js', and 'package.json'. The shop folder contains sub folders, Grutfile.js contains the module.exports etc.. file and package.json contains the { file. When I cd into the directory, am I support to target the root folder where these 3 main folders are located?

Comment: Please try `sudo npm install grunt-shopify --save-dev`

Comment: C:\Users\Steven\Desktop\Sublime Text 2>sudo npm install grunt-shopify --save-dev
'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.        <--  this is the output from the system i get

Comment: Thanks Norman. I think i got past this step. Much appreciated!

Comment: Your'e welcome. I didn't help much by the way since I usee  Linux for all development tasks.

Comment: I have another question i just recently posted regarding the last step. I didnt want to post here since i figured it was a new question. think you can take a look for me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28338824/how-to-use-sublime-text-2-for-grunt-shopify