# how to use sublime text 2 for grunt-shopify

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, sublimetext2, shopify

I am very new to Node.js, Grunt and even Sublime text 2

Following this short tutorial: https://www.otreva.com/web-development/shopify-desktop-theme-editor-windows-linux/

I think I've finally reached the 6th (last) step. All I need to know is how to complete step 6 '`grunt watch:shopify`'

Can anyone give me a pointer on this? Where and how do I `Start the Grunt and watch it upload your theme files within ‘/shop/’ each time you modify and save them! Make sure you leave the terminal window open.` ?

Thank you so much and I really appreciate it in advanced!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute the command `grunt watch:shopify` at the /shop folder root. You need to leave the window(in which you run that command) open and then start making changes to your asset files. If all has been setup correctly, you should see notifications in the terminal window left open.

Comment: Thanks!! That makes complete sense. How would I execute a command? Im using command promp

Comment: You just need to type that command and hit enter I think in the command prompt. Also make sure grunt is installed globally. The command for that is `npm install -g grunt-cli`

Comment: Thanks! so I get this message now: `(node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use s
etImmediate for recursive deferral.
(node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use s
etImmediate for recursive deferral.`


`1node.js:0
// Copyright Joyent, Inc. and other Node contributors.
^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: The first node error is outputted about 50 times before the `1note.js0` is outputted.

Comment: I think this is a node related version problem that will take a lot of solving to do. Please make sure all your software is updated. What I can think of from this error is its module code that is outdated.

Comment: hmm i just freshly installed node and its the latest version. Ill see if i can find anything else and let you know. And again, thank you guys so much

Comment: I backtracked to the point where i think i was last safe. Again, back on step 5 of the tutorial as mentioned in this post, I get this message below which seems likes it is working, but the `npm WARN package.json etc..` scares me.. could this be where the problem is?

Comment: `C:\Users\Steven\Desktop\Sublime Text 2\shop>npm install https://github.com/mjaverto/grunt-shopify/tarball/mast
er
npm WARN package.json ShopifyNameYouMakeUp@0.1.0 No description
npm WARN package.json ShopifyNameYouMakeUp@0.1.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json ShopifyNameYouMakeUp@0.1.0 No README data
growl@1.7.0 node_modules\growl

grunt-contrib-watch@0.4.4 node_modules\grunt-contrib-watch
├── tiny-lr@0.0.4 (debug@0.7.4, faye-websocket@0.4.4, noptify@0.0.3, qs@0.5.6)
└── gaze@0.3.4 (minimatch@0.2.14, fileset@0.1.5)
`

Comment: (continued)
`grunt@0.4.5 node_modules\grunt
├── dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3
├── which@1.0.8
├── eventemitter2@0.4.14
├── getobject@0.1.0
├── rimraf@2.2.8
├── colors@0.6.2
├── async@0.1.22
├── hooker@0.2.3
├── grunt-legacy-util@0.2.0
├── exit@0.1.2
├── minimatch@0.2.14 (sigmund@1.0.0, lru-cache@2.5.0)
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.5)
├── lodash@0.9.2
├── glob@3.1.21 (inherits@1.0.0, graceful-fs@1.2.3)
├── coffee-script@1.3.3
├── underscore.string@2.2.1
├── iconv-lite@0.2.11
├── findup-sync@0.1.3 (glob@3.2.11, lodash@2.4.1)
`

Comment: (continued)`├── grunt-legacy-log@0.1.1 (underscore.string@2.3.3, lodash@2.4.1)
└── js-yaml@2.0.5 (esprima@1.0.4, argparse@0.1.16)

grunt-shopify@0.3.0 node_modules\grunt-shopify
└── glob@3.2.11 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@0.3.0)`